# Fill GridView with TextBoxes and Dropdownlist from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have GridView:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
                                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="True">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="fullName"  />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="situation>">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="dl_situation" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="procesVerbal">
 <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="tbNr" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>  

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data">
<ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>     
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now I want to fill this Grid with data from database, I have one method that returns datatable with all my data

when I fill mygrid:

```
 MyGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
 MyGridView.Databind();
```

in this case all TextBoxes and DropDownList are null.

In the code below I'm trying to create a function that receives DataTable from database and populates gridview with data. How do I make a foreach statement for dataTable.Rows that will assign text values to TextBox elements and selectedIndex value to DropDownList?

```
protected bool FillGridWithData(DataTable dataTable)
       {bool result;
       try
       {
           foreach (GridViewRow row in MyGridView1.Rows)
           {
               if (row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) break;
               var ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("dl_situation");
               if (ddl != null)
               {
                 ddl.DataSource = PublicStatic.Situation;
                 ddl.DataTextField = PublicStatic.Name;
                 ddl.DataValueField = PublicStatic.Code;
                 ddl.DataBind();
                 ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
                 ddl.SelectedIndex = //data from datatable;
               }
               var tb1 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("tbNr");
               if (tb1 != null)
                   tb1.Text =//data from datatable;

               var tb2 = (TextBox)row.FindControl("tbDate");
               if (tb2 != null)
                   tb2.Text = //data from datatable;
           }
           result = true;
       }
       catch (Exception exception)
       {
           result = false;
       }
       return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataField` attribute in the bound field must equal to the `column name` in the datatable.
For binding textboxes in the template field you can use the Eval or Bind Method.

**Example:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="procesVerbal">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="tbNr" Text='<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and for binding the dropdown in the gridview, you can use a separate sql datasource. and specify dropdownlist DataSourceID,DataTextField and DataValueField property.

**Dropdownlist Example:**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ProductName" DataValueField="ProductID" ></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductName], [ProductID] FROM [Alphabetical list of products]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and if you want to bind the datasource from code behind then you can use `RowDataBound` event of gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {           
        TextBox t = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("ControlID"); 
        t.Text = "Some Text";
    }
```

}

Comment: What if I have a few textboxes and I want to populate a GridView from the information from those textboxes.